# Wait to load plugin to execute other Jquery

Tags: jquery, plugins, load

I'm using two plugins:

1) Load tweets
2) Paginate those tweets

But need to load the tweets for paginate. I use the following code but not working

```
$(document).ready( function(){ 
$("#twittTime").tweet({
    avatar_size: 32,
    count: 20,
    fetch: 20,
    template: "{text} {time}",
    filter: function(t){ return ! /^@\w+/.test(t["tweet_raw_text"]); },
    username: "user",
    loading_text: "Cargando Timeline ..."
});

$(".tweet_list").live({ load: function() {
    $('.tweet_list').easyPaginate({
            step:4,
            alert: 'Hola'
    }); 
},
});
});
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm the maintainer of `jquery.tweet.js`. The widget triggers a "loaded" event after the tweets have been rendered into the page, so you can simply do this:

```
$(document).ready( function(){ 
$("#twittTime").tweet({
    avatar_size: 32,
    count: 20,
    fetch: 20,
    template: "{text} {time}",
    filter: function(t){ return ! /^@\w+/.test(t["tweet_raw_text"]); },
    username: "user",
    loading_text: "Cargando Timeline ..."
}).bind("loaded",  function() {
    $('.tweet_list').easyPaginate({
            step:4,
            alert: 'Hola'
    }); 
});
});
```

There's an example of that in the bundled `index.html` file and on the [tweet.seaofclouds.com](http://tweet.seaofclouds.com) page.

Answer (score 1):

The plugin should have a callback method that tells you when it's complete. From there you run your `$(".tweet_list")` function.

EDIT:

I'm editing here because it's better for showing code examples. If you can edit the JS plugin I would suggest adding in your own callback...it's really, really easy.

First lets add a `complete()` method to the plugin. If you open `tweet.js` then look for `var s = $.extend({`, this is where the defaults are set for the plugin. Inside the `$.extend()` method there will be a list of settings, go all the way down to the bottom and add this:

Roughly line #30:

```
filter: function(tweet) {
    return true;
},
/* Our callback method we are adding */
complete: function() {
    return true;
}
```

Then we need to call this function at the end of the JSON AJAX request.

Go down to line #201 just under the `if (s.refresh_interval)` statement. Then after the closing `}` add `s.complete();`

What you've basically done is call the complete function after the content has loaded. I tested it locally and it's working so try it out and see if it does what you're looking for.

Good luck!

Edit 2: I found the plugin on Github and submitted this feature so hopefully when/if they come out with an update it will have this so you don't have to add it every time.

Comment: Thanks dude, I'm using http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/ but don't have a callback method, can u help me please?

Comment: I updated my post with a way to do it. It will require that you update the plugin source, but shouldn't break anything.